# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages Exception Handling breaks the application

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

I'm building an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages Application. I'm writing an global exception handling to avoid try catch blocks in many places. I followed the article - [Exception Handling Reference](https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-error-and-exception-handling)

Here is the [Demo Solution Link](https://github.com/fingers10/ModelValidation)

Here is my code,

In **Startup.cs**

```
if(env.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions {
    //    SourceCodeLineCount = 2
    //});
    //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseExceptionMiddleware();
} else {...}
```

In **ExceptionMiddleware.cs**

```
public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,IMailService emailSender)
{
    _next = next;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        EmailException(context,ex);
    }
}

private async void EmailException(HttpContext context,Exception ex)
{
    var uaString = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
    var ipAnonymizedString = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.AnonymizeIP();
    var userId = "Unknown";
    var profileId = "Unknown";
    if(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        userId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        profileId = context.User.GetUserClaim(ClaimsKey.ProfileId);
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder($"An error has occurred on {context.Request.Host}. \r\n \r\n");
    sb.Append($"Path = {context.Request.Path} \r\n \r\n");
    sb.Append($"Error Message = {ex.Message} \r\n");
    sb.Append($"Error Source = {ex.Source} - {profileId} \r\n");

    if(ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        sb.Append($"Inner Exception = {ex.InnerException.ToString()} \r\n");
    } else
    {
        sb.Append("Inner Exception = null \r\n");
    }

    sb.Append($"Error StackTrace = {ex.StackTrace} \r\n");

    await _emailSender.SendMasterEmailAsync($"Error on {context.Request.Host}.",sb.ToString(),uaString,ipAnonymizedString,userId);

    throw ex;
}
```

Now, I'm creating an exception in one of my page get request as shown below,

```
public void OnGet()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The middleware catches the exception and it's throwing that after sending email. Then Visual Studio says application is in break mode and visual studio stops. But my **Error.cshtml.cs** is not capturing the exception before that application breaks and stops. Any Idea of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his [async guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void) GitHub repository, David Fowler states that:

> Use of async void in ASP.NET Core applications is **ALWAYS** bad. Avoid it, never do it. Typically, it's used when developers are trying to implement fire and forget patterns triggered by a controller action. Async void methods will crash the process if an exception is thrown.

For the error you're describing, that last line is crucial - your application *is* throwing an exception, which is crashing the process.

For `EmailException`, you should switch from using `async void` to using `async Task`, like this:

```
public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,IMailService emailSender)
{
    ...
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await EmailException(context, ex); // Await.
    }
}

private async Task EmailException(HttpContext context, Exception ex) // Return a Task.
{
    ...

    throw ex;
}
```

If the reason you're trying to use `async void` is so that you don't have to wait for the email to be sent before returning a response to the user, you might want to look at using a [Background Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for that.